# Do we need to specify an alias in view if its definition has a column with unique constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-view

Oracle specifies ["you must specify aliases if the view definition includes constraints."](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm)
But in the following query the column email has a unique constraint,but no alias.Yet this works fine.Why?

```
CREATE VIEW emp_sal (emp_id, last_name, 
      email UNIQUE RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE,
   CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (emp_id) RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE)
   AS SELECT employee_id, last_name, email FROM employees;
```

Comment: You **are** using aliases. In the part `emp_sal( emp_id, last_name, ...)`, `emp_id` and `last_name` are the aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, there are aliases in your view definition:

```
CREATE VIEW emp_sal (emp_id, last_name, 
      email UNIQUE RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE,
   CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (emp_id) RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE)
   AS SELECT employee_id, last_name, email FROM employees;
```

Here `emp_id, last_name, email` are nothing but aliases.